# Simple GridViewColumn binding question

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `ListView` with a few `GridViewColumn`. One of the columns I am showing the visibility of layers and I binded the icon and the opacity, but I am not sure how to bind it to a property called `IsVisible` so that whenever an item is clicked in that column, it will toggle the `IsVisible` boolean value.

Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<GridViewColumn Width="20">
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="X" />
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="18"
                Height="18"
                Source="{Binding VisibleIcon}"
                        Opacity="{Binding VisibleOpacity}"
                        />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Additionally, `VisibleOpacity` defines the `Opacity` for the icon but I feel like this is not a good way to do it because I had to create this property solely for this purpose. Is there a way to do this inline in xaml? Maybe like:

```
Opacity = (this.IsVisible) ? 1 : 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :** ok, so I think this should be good now..

Still assuming that your collection is a collection of :

```
public class Effect : INotifyPropertychanged
{
    //Some properties


    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible;}
        set { isVisible=value;//plus raise propertychanged notification}
    }      
}
```

then I think the simplest way to propagate the image click both to your code property and to the image opacity is to wrap your icon in a toggle button. Here is a code I have used and tested. Just replace the values by yours and put this in your data template, it should work fine this time :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="tgBtn" Height="20" Width="20" IsChecked="{Binding IsVisible}" 
              BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" >
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Width="18"
                           Height="18"                 
                           Source="C:\USERS\thumbnail.jpeg">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tgBtn, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Thanks, the `IsVisible` property is inside each instance of `Effect`, so I did this but didn't work:                                                 `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Effect, Path=IsVisible}" Value="false">`
Did I do wrong?

Comment: If the list is data-bound to a list of instances that have an IsVisible property, I don't think you want the ElementName attribute in the {Binding}, just the Path.

Comment: Thanks Craig, it's already bounded to a list. So I should just use `Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}"`. This gets rid of the binding error printed in the output window, but I don't see the opacity change.

Comment: Also in the setter of IsVisible I printed the value when it's changed but nothing is printed so it didn't bind correctly I think.

Comment: I have edited my answer. But don't forget that for the opacity to get updated when changeing the value of your object property, you must raise the notify property changed event so that the XAML trigger could be... well.. triggered

Comment: Thanks Bruno, it makes sense now. But I tried like you said, it didn't do anything. Basically here is the code `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="false">` and the property code is `bool isVisible;
public bool IsVisible
{
 get { return isVisible; }
 set
 {
  this.isVisible = value;
  this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "IsVisible" );
  Console.WriteLine ( value );
 }
}` but it doesn't print anything when I click on the image inside the listview column.

Comment: yeah, I think I misunderstood your problem... I thought you wanted notification from your property To XAML, but it seems that you want is the other way (from XAML to your property). sorry about that....

Answer (score 1):

Don't know that you need the Opacity value to change. What you need to bind is the Image's Visibility property, and use a converter to get from the boolean IsVisible to the Visibility enum value.

See http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/07/visibility-type-converter/